# run servo motor with external power bosen't work for me

Tags: pi-4

I use 9v/0.5A DC cable to breadboard and connect servo motor but it doesn't work. Code might be wrong but I'm not sure.

I connect raspberry pi - breadboard - servo motor like this

[image: red:(+), balck:gound(-), orange:GPIO12]

and this is the code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO     
from time import sleep      

print('1')
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)      
print('2')
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

servo_pin = 12                   
print('3')
GPIO.setup(servo_pin, GPIO.OUT)  
servo = GPIO.PWM(servo_pin, 50)  
servo.start(0)  

servo_min_duty = 3               
servo_max_duty = 12              
print('4')
def set_servo_degree(degree):    

    if degree > 180:
        degree = 180
    elif degree < 0:
        degree = 0

    
    duty = servo_min_duty+(degree*(servo_max_duty-servo_min_duty)/180.0)
    
    servo.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)
print('5')

try:                                    
    while True:                         
        set_servo_degree(0)             
        sleep(1)                        
        set_servo_degree(90)
        sleep(1)
        set_servo_degree(120)
        sleep(1)
        set_servo_degree(180)
        sleep(1)
        print('6')



finally:                                
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't appear to be connected to anything.

Comment: You are using wire colors indiscriminately. For example, you are using two black wires, one as ground, one as power.

Comment: why do you hide connections in the picture?

Comment: You need to provide clear photos so that we can follow all the connections.  To me it looks like you have connected both servo ground and power to the breadboard 5V rail.